# Swift Subscribe User to Topics After FCM Token Refreshes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, subscribe

I subscribe users to topics elsewhere in my code so they can get group chat notifications. Is the token used to subscribe a user to a topic the same one as fcmToken received in the App Delegate below? If it changes, I'd need to subscribe users again to their existing chats using the refreshed registration token in didRefreshRegistrationToken, right? Would the topics contain the old token as well and how would I get rid of them so it just contains the current tokens?

```swift
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser,
           let userData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.currentUser) as? Data,
           let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userData) {
            User.setCurrent(user)
            UserService.updateChildS(child: "userToken", childVal: fcmToken)
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "fcmToken")
        }

    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        UserService.show(forUID: User.current.uid) { (user) in
            if let user = user {
                for group in user.groups {
                    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: group.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) { error in

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        UserService.updateChildS(child: "userToken", childVal: fcmToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear as to what you are trying to achieve, could you edit your question and be as specific as you can?

Comment: I'm just wondering if the fcmToken in the functions above didReceiveRegistrationToken and didRefreshRegistrationToken is the same one used to subscribe a user to topics on Firebase. And basically when the fcmToken refreshes if I need to re-subscribe users to those topics.